# Указатели и массивы C++

Tags: c, указатели, c++

Почему выводится значение массива, а не адрес?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[] = "dom";
    char *p;            // объявление указателя

    p = &s[0];          // взятие адреса

    cout << p << endl;  // вывод на консоль указателя
    // почему выводится значение массива а не адрес?

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это потому, что в C++ оператор << так для char\* определен. Выводить не адрес, а содержимое, аналогично формату %s в printf().

Не помню, как задавать форматы для <<. Напишите просто в printf().

Comment: Т.е вам надо получить область памяти, где хранится массив "s"?

Comment: Нет, просто я хотел узнать ,через указатель можно вывести адрес массива?

Comment: @Андрей2, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно привести указатель к типу void*:

```
 cout << (void*) p << endl;
```

Comment: Не си-плюс-плюсно...

        cout << static_cast<void*> (p) << endl;

Comment: А вообще-то форматированный вывод в C++ **это нечто**. Смотрите:

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int k=1;
    //int hex = 0x0008;
    cout << "Input zero for close\n";
    while(k){
      cout<<"input number: ";  cin>>k;
      cout<<"dec: "<<k<<hex<<", hex: "<<k<<dec<<endl;
    }
    }

А теперь раскомментарьте int hex.

Comment: @avp а если букварь почитать? Главу "области видимости"?

Comment: @alexlz, а объясните "на пальцах", зачем так много букв ? 

Имеется в виду 

    static_cast<void*>

вместо

    (void*)

Comment: @avp,  ну и что?

Comment: @avp Насчёт static_cast. Я же написал -- не си-плюс-плюсно. Вместо одного (работающего как ломик) приведения, в C++ несколько, каждый для своих случаев, с некоторыми проверками. Допустим (int) p пройдёт нормально, а static_cast<int> (p) вызовет некоторую ругань

     error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘int’

А с учётом политики, что приведений типа д.б. как можно меньше, "много букв" -- не недостаток, а достоинство.

Comment: Объяснения не понял. 

Кратко - в каких случаях (с какой целью, какую выгоду дает и т.п.) помогают *некоторые проверки*.

--

"много букв" -- не недостаток, а достоинство.

Особенно для индийских программистов. Говорят, им за объем кода платят.

Comment: @alexlz,

    @avp а если букварь почитать? Главу "области видимости"?

а если не читать и добавить переменную одноименную с одним из enum fmt_flags что будет ? 

Я о том, что **компилятор-то не ловит !!!**

Comment: @avp Вас не понять. Два противоречащих друг другу вопроса. 1."помогают некоторые проверки." -- уменьшение дырки в системе типов , и, соответственно, уменьшение количества потенциальных ошибок -- "зачем"? 2. Реализовано задание форматов через манипуляторы. Можно задать локальную переменную с именем манипулятора и вывод будет работать по-другому. Компилятор такого поймать не может по определению. "Почему". На вопрос "что делать" -- не пользоваться манипуляторами. Задать формат и методами cout можно. А вообще, важна безопасность -- пользуйтесь более безопасными инструментами, чем монстроидный C+

Comment: Я считаю все эти cast'ы только дополнительное закостыливание языка. В других Си-подобных языках такого нет. Там единый синтаксис для всех приведений: в C# C-style (void*)p, в D - cast(void*)p.

Answer (score 1):

Да, у Вас будет **p == s**.  (это ответ на первоначальную версию вопроса)

Например t.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  char s[] = "dom ";
  char *p = &s[0], *q = s;

  printf ("p %p q %p s %p\n",p,q,s);
}
```

Получаем

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ gcc t.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
p 0xbfaeb6c7 q 0xbfaeb6c7 s 0xbfaeb6c7
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Comment: @alexlz, к сожалению в ветке с ответом @mikillskegg  у меня лимит комментариев закончился. Поэтому отвечаю здесь.

Вы можете **конкретно** объяснить:

 **зачем** вместо *(void\*)* Вы предлагаете писать *static_cast<void\*>* ?

Comment: @avp Для порядка. Чтобы таких конструкций в тексте не было, и потом не надо было думать, безопасна такая штука здесь или нет. На нет и суда нет. Будут явные cast'ы, для которых надо думать, подойдёт он здесь или нет, а компилятор проверит, насколько подумал. 

Т.е. в принципе вопрос стиля.

Comment: @alexlz, ну, что же, действительно

    На нет и суда нет

Comment: @GLmonster Закостыливание языка? Возможно. Но что уж выросло, то выросло. (А какие дискуссии были когда-то по поводу совместимости C++ с C...)

Comment: @alexlz, по сути это продолжение такой же дискуссии. Тема *стоит ли в реальной жизни пользоваться возможностями C++ и если да, то какими ?*.

Comment: @avp Однозначно стоит. Доработка старых проектов, наличие разработчиков для новых и т.д. Но, по возможности, лучше от него отходить.